# After upgrading Sitecore & Glass mapper ISitecoreContext.GetCurrentItem<T>() returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, glass-mapper

We are upgrading to the latest version of Sitecore and at the same time upgrading to the latest version of glass mapper available on nuget.

Our code which worked up until we started the glass mapper upgrade has started to fail because our custom types are not being inflated correctly by glass mapper.

It is also important to note that we are not using Windsor as our DI container, we have selected the latest version of Autofac, and subsequently had to configure glass mapper to work with our container.

```
            var page = _context.GetCurrentItem<CarouselPage>();
```

This method call once returned a fully inflated object, but now it just returns the new instance created by glass mapper. With either null properties, or dynamic types with null properties.

```
    [SitecoreType(TemplateId = "0539B72D-FAAC-49DE-8A42-C60D7FF180DD")]
public class CarouselPage : ICarousel
{
    [SitecoreField()]
    [SitecoreEditable]
    public virtual IEnumerable<CarouselItem> Carousel { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Overlay Style")]
    public virtual bool OverlayStyle { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Carousel Pagination Alignment", FieldType = SitecoreFieldType.Droplink)]
    public KeyValue CarouselDotAlignment { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Equalize Desktop", FieldType = SitecoreFieldType.Droplink)]
    public KeyValue EqualizeDesktopText { get; set; }
}

    public interface ICarousel
{
    IEnumerable<CarouselItem> Carousel { get; set; } 
}
```

The property `Carousel` is NULL, but `CarouselDotAlignment` and `EqualizeDesktopText` are new dynamic instances of the type `KeyValue` with their own properties equal to NULL.

If I bypass glass mapper and make a call to 
`Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem({id})` I actually get an Item back with what appears to be the proper fields. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: Due to time constraints we reverted the upgrade of glass mapper and continued forward with the old glass mapper binaries against the latest version of Sitecore. It is unlikely we will come back to this issue, sorry.

Comment: I had the same issue and resolved it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264897/sitecore-glass-mapper-always-null

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the properties may not have been configured correctly, I would check what Glass.Mapper thinks is configured by using the following code:

```
        var result = Glass.Mapper.Context.Default.TypeConfigurations[typeof(MyModel)];
        var properties = result.Properties.Count();
```

The result object will allow you to explore what Glass thinks should be happening.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to this issue [#132](https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/issues/132) 
Updating the Nuget package to v4.0.1.5 should fix that.