# Sitecore Glass Mapper always null

Tags: sitecore, code-generation, glass-mapper, tds, sitecore7.2

I am using Sitecore Glass Mapper for a new project I'm setting up.
We are using Sitecore 7.2, latest version of Team Development for Sitecore (TDS) code generation and the latest version of glass.

The code I am trying to execute:

```
var b = new SitecoreContext();
var c = b.GetCurrentItem<T01_Homepage>();
```

b is not null. c is null.

```
var d = b.GetItem<T01_Homepage>("path")
```

d is null.

I added my assembly in GlassMapperScCustom:

```
public static IConfigurationLoader[] GlassLoaders(){            

    var attributes = new AttributeConfigurationLoader(new[] { "Company.Framework.Websites.Corporate", "Company.Framework.Core", "Company.Framework.Common" });

    return new IConfigurationLoader[] { attributes };
}
```

When I look into b.GlassContext.TypeConfigurations all my models are there.

I figured it could be a language issue because the site is in dutch and maybe the wrong language would be resolved incorrectly. This was also not the case.

I disabled WebActivator and added the GlassMapperSc.Start() in my Global.asax Application_Start method.

We are also using Autofac as DI framework. But without it, it still isn't working as you can see above. Also when I create my own custom models without TDS code generation the result of `GetCurrentItem<T>` is null.

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check your Sites.config and the default language for this website? There could be a difference between the language which is defined in your Sitecore languages folder and your configuration.

I had a similar problem with one of my projects where I changed the Sitecore.Context.Language to "nl" instead of "nl-NL". The glass mapper will return null, but Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem will return an object in this case.

Comment: That did the trick. My language was nl-nl and in sites.config the sites/site node had the attribute language on nl. Thanks.

Comment: This is interesting - I am having a similar problem, and indeed when I inspect the root of my website the language seems to be set to "hr" - a value that I never explicitely set, but it's the name of a first-level child of my website that I have since removed:

http://screencast.com/t/aMhy7yl3

Could this have somehow made Sitecore/Glass.Mapper think that "hr" (Croatian) should be the language, thus returning a null item?

Comment: @HansLeautaud where do I find Sites.config in inetpub folder?

Comment: @Sidso, I do not know anymore. The topic is 6 years old.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times it is a language issue. The mapper returns a null object when you do not have versions in the current or given language.

What can be confusing is that Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem returns an object, even if it does not have a version in the current language. Be sure to check that item.Versions has any.

Comment: Thanks, this response in combination with the response of Aldentev did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Some things you may try (this didn't fit in the comments field)

1) Confirm that the related fields in the Sitecore Item object contain values (so `Sitecore.Context.Item` for your "c" var and `Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("path")` for your "d" var)

2) Try to encapsulate the GetItem/GetCurrentItem call in a `VersionCountDisabler`, like this:

```
T01_Homepage model = null;

using (new VersionCountDisabler())
{
  var context = new SitecoreContext();
  model = context.GetItem<T01_Homepage>("path");
}

// Do you have data in model now?
```

3) Try to encapsulate the same call with a `SecurityDisabler`. Just to confirm it's not a security issue.

4) If you still don't know what it is, please update your question with some (simplified) code for your model.