# Sitecore Glass mapper GetItem<TypeName>(guid) always return null

Tags: orm, sitecore, code-generation, glass-mapper, tds

I saw a related question:
[Sitecore Glass Mapper always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264897/sitecore-glass-mapper-always-null)

But unfortunately it does not give a solution for my case.

Here goes a code snippet:

```csharp
var db = Factory.GetDatabase("master");
var context = new SitecoreContext();
// the ID of Needed item
var g = new Guid("{F21C04FE-8826-41AB-9F3C-F7BDF5B35C76}");
// just to test if it's possible to fetch item using db.GetItem
var i = db.GetItem(new ID(g), Language.Current, Sitecore.Data.Version.Latest);
// Grab item
var t = context.GetItem<Article>(g);
```

In the code above:
 i is not null
 t is null

Article is the simple class like:

```csharp
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{4C4EC1DA-EB77-4001-A7F9-E4C2F61A9BE9}")]
public class Article
{
    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

There are only one language installed in Sitecore - en, it has been specified in the web.config in the  items as well.

Also I have added `GlassMapperSc.Start();` to `Application_Start` in the `Global.asax.cs` and added my assembly to the list of included assemblies via `var attributes = new AttributeConfigurationLoader(new[] { "Assembly.Name" });` and I succeeded to find my class in the `SitecoreContext` mappings.

It does not looks like a language issue, as stated in the link provided in the very beginning. And I'm struggling with it already for a pretty long time, but no luck...

Thank You!

Comment: Just to be sure, did you check that your item `{F21C04FE-8826-41AB-9F3C-F7BDF5B35C76}` has a valid version?

Comment: Using the standard Sitecore API get the item and check that it is in the language you expect and also has a version. I have seen problems where (and for no reason) SC is using a different language to the one you think it should be using.

Comment: @michael-edwards I checked it out, it has langage 'en' and version '1'.

Comment: Did you try to cast (i) directly using "i.GlassCast<Article>(true,true)" ? Also "Title" needs to be virtual.

Comment: @ahmed-okour Thank You! i.GlassCast<Article>(true,true) and adding a virtual to the Title helped me, but GetItem<Article>(g) still returns null for some reason.

Comment: Could be a bug from Glass, not sure, however, i've been using GlassCast() method all the time, didn't have any issues with it so far

Comment: Even if the item has a version, it might be in a workflow state that isn't "final". With default settings, Sitecore would return a version-less item for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just noticed that you are using master db for the Sitecore DB and  `SitecoreContext` for Glass.

The `SitecoreContext` class will use the database that is defined by the `Sitecore.Context.Database` property at runtime. This probably means that it is using the web database.

Can you check that you have published the item to the web database or instead using:

```cs
var context = new SitecoreService("master");
```