# Sitecore Glass mapper GetItem<TypeName>(itemPath) returns null when casting as custom type

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper, sitecore-mvc, tds

When I use Glass Mapper's `SitecoreContext().GetItem<Sitecore.Data.Items.Item>(ItemPath)` it works fine, but as soon as I use it with my custom model generated by TDS + Glass it returns `null`.

My code is as follows:

*NavigationHelper.cs*

```cs
public class NavigationHelper
{
    public static int GetChildCount()
    {
        var context = new SitecoreContext();
        string g = "/sitecore/content/home/Site Settings/Top Navigation Items";

        var t = context.GetItem<Models.sitecore.templates.Navigation.Navigation_Item_Folder>(g);
        var v = context.GetItem<Items.Item>(g);
        // t is always null, but v always finds the item correctly.
        return t.Children.Count();
    }
}
```

`Models.sitecore.templates.Navigation.Navigation_Item_Folder` is a model generated by Glass and TDS and as follows:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Navigation_Item_Folder
/// <para></para>
/// <para>Path: /sitecore/templates/Navigation/Navigation Item Folder</para>    
/// <para>ID: c0f00c6b-145e-47f2-9427-57df58a612f1</para>   
/// </summary>
[SitecoreType(TemplateId=INavigation_Item_FolderConstants.TemplateIdString)] //, Cachable = true
public partial class Navigation_Item_Folder  : GlassBase, INavigation_Item_Folder 
{

}
```

It's just a folder, so it has no fields on it.  I've tried extending this partial class to include a title field, but that didn't fix the issue.

I have already tried the steps here: [Sitecore Glass mapper GetItem<TypeName>(guid) always return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24521113/sitecore-glass-mapper-getitemtypenameguid-always-return-null) but they haven't helped.

Comment: Sitecore API will return an Item object if it exists but Glass will only return objects if it also has any version in the current language. You could check if v.Versions has any. I believe v4 has a config setting for this to modify behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try the guid as `{C0F00C6B-145E-47F2-9427-57DF58A612F1}`? I've seen standard Sitecore queries have case sensitivity issues when locating an item by template id.

Comment: I believe that is the issue. We added a `.ToUpper()` in the `.tt` file for the `TemplateIdString` field in the `xxxxxConstants` class part. It's around line 99 if you are using `glassv3item.tt`.